# Photo not displayed when selected from photo library in Ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, camera, ionic2

I am using Camera plugin in Ionic 2 for uploading photos. I am running the app on an Android device. The Carema capture is displayed in the app but when selected from Gallery the photo is not displayed.

The following methods are used for Camera and Gallary:

```
  private openCamera(){
    var options: CameraOptions = {
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      allowEdit: true,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.cameraData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.photoTaken = true;
      this.photoSelected = false;
 let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  }, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});

  }

    private selectFromGallery() {
    var options = {
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.cameraUrl = imageData;
      this.photoSelected = true;
      this.photoTaken = false;
    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

Following is the code to display in HTML page:

```
<img [src]="cameraData" *ngIf="photoTaken">
<img [src]="cameraUrl" *ngIf="photoSelected">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a file plugin to obtain local filesystem url when you select from library.

To install:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

Import:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
```

and in your code:

```
constructor( private file: File, .... ) {}

.....


const options: CameraOptions = {
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageURI) => {
  this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(imageURI).then(fileEntry => {

    this.cameraUrl = fileEntry.nativeURL;
    this.photoSelected = true;
    this.photoTaken = false;
  });
}, (err) => {
  // Handle error
});
```

**EDIT**

You might need to sanitize the value for img src:

```
<img *ngIf="cameraUrl" [src]="sanitizeUrl(cameraUrl)"   />
```

The function:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

....

constructor( private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, .... ) {}

....

sanitizeUrl(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution. I think the code has a small issue. I tried with `this.cameraUrl =fileEntry.nativeURL`. This worked in IOS simulator but in Android phone a small broken image icon is coming. Not the picture. Any solutions?

Comment: Try to console.log(this.cameraUrl) to see what it returns. You might need to sanitize the url - see edit of my post above

Comment: bypassSecurityTrustUrl worked. I passed fileEntry.nativeURL in it and now its displayed in both IOS and Android. Thank you. :)